# Search between dates with a variable interval w/ rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, datetime

I am wondering how this can be handled via a db query instead of looking up all of the sites.

```
Site.all.select { |x| x.last_ran <= DateTime.now - x.interval.minutes }
```

Basically i need to find all the sites that were last_ran before their interval. So if i ran my site at 12:00 and its 12:06 but the interval is 5 minutes, then it would be returned by this query.

The problem im having is converting x.interval.minutes (5.minutes) at the database level.

Thanks - Also im using postgres if there a db specific way to do this!

Comment: I would strongly advise adding a `NextRunDueBy` field.  Such a field will allow you to use an index to fulfil this query.  At present *every* row will need parsing *every* time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postgres this would work...

```
Site.where(
  "sites.last_ran <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - sites.interval * INTERVAL '1 second'"
)
```

I think you could use either `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: The interval is integer. is there a better datatype?

Comment: An integer indicating what?  How does `x.interval.minutes` work if `interval` is itself already an integer?

Comment: rails adds minutes method on the integer type so i can do DateTime.now - 5.minutes or (x.interval.minutes).